# how can I export multiple divs to one pdf file by using kendo?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

This is Kendo's example code about how to export DOM to pdf

```html
<div id="calendar"></div>
<script>
    $("#calendar").kendoCalendar();

    var draw = kendo.drawing;

    draw.drawDOM($("#calendar"))
    .then(function(root) {
        // Chaining the promise via then
        return draw.exportPDF(root, {
            paperSize: "A4",
            landscape: true
        });
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        // Here 'data' is the Base64-encoded PDF file
        kendo.saveAs({
            dataURI: data,
            fileName: "calendar.pdf"
        });
    });
</script>
```

What if I have multiple divs to export? For example, I have #calendar1, #calendar2, and I'd like to export all #calendars into one pdf file. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I find an answer in this example.

[Telerik PDF Export](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/pdf-export/index)